# Parallel circuit 5V delivery (PCB)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium

There is +5V input from the pin you see on the left below. The goal is to supply 5V to each of the two pads in the picture below. Does the trace layout accomplish this?

I ask this because when I converted the Altium schematic to the PCB, the trace appeared to be connected in series: trace started from pin and connected to the pad in the top of the picture, then another trace started from the top pad to the pad in the bottom of the picture. Are the pads not connected in series this way such that exactly 5V will not be supplied to each of the pads?

[image: pcb]

Comment: It will supply 5v, but it may or may not actually work in your system depending on what the loads are, what their current requirements are and what the di/dt is for those lines.  Note that you not only have to worry about the 5v net, you also have to have a ground connection to make a circuit.

Comment: Will 25mil trace width still work if the trace width calculator calculates 30mil?

Comment: @Kevin Depends on whether you can tolerate the voltage drop. Calculate the resistance of the trace, then calculate how much of your 5V will actually make it to the pads when the circuit draws maximum current.